# Update AppBar title from body widget in Scaffold

Tags: exception, events, flutter, setstate

I am starting to use flutter and doing the 'Startup Name Generator' tutorial, also modifying the code to do some different things, and have come across an issue I can't solve. I want the AppBar title to show the size of the _suggestions array, but can't get it to work, have tried many different things but to no avail, always getting the exception of trying to use 'setState()' while already in a build.

This is what I currently have:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:english_words/english_words.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Startup Name Generator',
      home: RandomWords(),
    );
  }
}

class RandomWordsState extends State<RandomWords> {
  static final _suggestions = <WordPair>[];
  final _biggerFont = const TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0);
  ValueNotifier<String> appBarTitleNotifier = ValueNotifier('Startup Name Generator: 0');

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(title: ValueListenableBuilder<String>(
        valueListenable: appBarTitleNotifier,
        builder: (context,value,child) {
          return Text(value);
        }
      )),
      body: _buildSuggestions(),
    );

  }

  Widget _buildSuggestions() {
    var blder = ListView.builder(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
      itemBuilder: /*1*/ (context, i) {
        if (i.isOdd) return Divider(); /*2*/

        final index = i ~/2; /*3*/
        if (index >= _suggestions.length) {
          _suggestions.addAll(generateWordPairs().take(10)); /*4*/

/**** THIS NEXT LINE CAUSES THE ISSUE ****/
          appBarTitleNotifier.value = 'Startup Name Generator: ' + _suggestions.length.toString();


        }
        return _buildRow(_suggestions[index],index);
      },



    );
    return blder;
  }

  Widget _buildRow(WordPair pair, int i) {

    return ListTile(
      title: Text(
        pair.asPascalCase + ': ' + i.toString(),
        style: _biggerFont,
      ),
    );
  }


}

class RandomWords extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  RandomWordsState createState() => RandomWordsState();
}
```

I have used a ValueNotifier and listener after doing some research into events, but same exception as when I manually used a setState() call within the ListView itemBuilder (where the issue seems to lie; calling/updating the AppBar title from within the ListView itemBuilder).

I haven't found a solution here so I am asking.  Sorry if this has already been answered, but I could not find the solution.

Comment: I don't see where `setState()` is in your code, but I just tried the sample default project, and had no issues changing AppBar title manually through a button, no listeners needed.

Comment: The setState is triggeted by the value of the valueNotifier changing. Yeah, easy to make it work with a button, but thays not what i want.  As the list is scrolled, new items are created and added to the suggestions list. I want that mechanism to update the title bar, not some button

Comment: Okay, I didn't have any issues triggering `appBarTitleNotifier` inside the `itemBuilder`, so you need to copy/paste the exception that you are getting, but you've also got a few oddities: 1. `static final _suggestions` remove `final`, 2. why does your ListView not have a `itemCount:`? If this doesn't work, I can post my working sample here.

Comment: additional note, trying to modify(add to) the list inside the `itemBuilder` is probably not recommended, it can cause some odd behaviors if not controlled well

Answer (score 0):

How about using GestureDetector.
onVerticalDragEnd event not executed. but onVerticalDragDown works.

```
// Copyright 2018 The Flutter team. All rights reserved.
// Use of this source code is governed by a BSD-style license that can be
// found in the LICENSE file.
import 'package:english_words/english_words.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Welcome to Flutter',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Welcome to Flutter'),
          toolbarHeight: 100.0,
        ),
        body: const Center(
          child: RandomWords(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class RandomWords extends StatefulWidget {
  const RandomWords({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<RandomWords> createState() => _RandomWordsState();
}

class _RandomWordsState extends State<RandomWords> {
  final _suggestions = <WordPair>[];
  final _biggerFont = const TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0);
  String title = "Startup Name Generator";

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(title),
      ),
      body: GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
          print('tap');
        },
        onVerticalDragDown : (details) {
          print('onVerticalDragDown');
          setState(() {
            title = "Startup Name Generator ("+_suggestions.length.toString()+")";
          });
        },
        onVerticalDragEnd : (details) {
          print('onVerticalDragEnd ');
          setState(() {
            title = "Startup Name Generator ("+_suggestions.length.toString()+")";
          });
        },
        child:
          // Padding(
          // padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          // child: Icon(
          //     Icons.lightbulb_outline,
          //     color: Colors.yellow.shade600,
          //     size: 60,
          //   ),
          // ),

          ListView.builder(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
            itemBuilder: (context, i) {
              if(i.isOdd) return const Divider();
              final index = i ~/ 2;
              if(index >= _suggestions.length) {
                _suggestions.addAll(generateWordPairs().take(10));
              }
              return ListTile(
                title: Text(
                  // index.toString() + ":" + _suggestions[index].asPascalCase,
                  _suggestions[index].asPascalCase,
                  style: _biggerFont,
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
      )
    );
  }
}
```